# SYN-ACK packet how to decide its source IP

Tags: sockets, tcp

In the process of TCP connection, the client first sends a SYN packet. When the server receives this packet, it will respond with a SYN-ACK packet. Here's my question: When the server constructs the SYN-ACK packet, how does it decide the packet's source IP? Will the server iterate its own interfaces or simply exchange the SYN packet's source and destination IPs.

Answer (score 1):

The system will just exchange the source and destination IPs.

Comment: Show me the source code, Or some prooves would be great!

Comment: What system are you using?

Comment: @Jarrywoo: unless the OS is open source, how do you expect someone to show you the source code for how the OS implements its IP swapping? Just use a packet sniffer, like Wireshark, to verify the behavior (or, if the OS is open source, then look at the source code yourself).

Comment: @Jarrywoo Suppose *you* provide some rational explanation why it would do anything *else?* Why for example would it 'iterate its own interfaces'? Why would it do something difficult when it could do something easy? The question doesn't make sense. There's no reason to disbelieve this answer.